# how to terminate process using TerminateProcess

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I am trying to terminate a set of processes using below code but only few are getting terminated so please suggest me better way to terminate all the processes.

```
hProc = OpenProcess( PROCESS_TERMINATE, FALSE, processID );

if ( hProc )
{
    if(WaitForSingleObject(hProc, INFINITE)!=WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {
        dwRet=(TerminateProcess(hProc, 0)?TA_SUCCESS_KILL:TA_FAILED);
    }
    else
    {
        dwRet = TA_SUCCESS_CLEAN;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens with the ones that aren't getting terminated?

Comment: The code posted only terminates the process if the wait function fails.  I don't think that's what you intended.  (It doesn't really make sense; the only way the wait function could fail is if the handle is invalid, in which case the terminate function will fail too.)

Comment: @Harry: No, his logic is right.  Wait for the process to exit, and if the wait times out, kick it harder.  Well, he should use a shorter timeout.

Comment: @BenVoigt: but there's no timeout!  *Edit:* oh, I guess that's what you meant by "should use a shorter timeout". :-)

Comment: So, yeah, if you change `INFINITE` to a finite period, that code would make sense.

Comment: @all thanks for your suggestion finally i came to know that there was nothing wrong with the logic, i just needed to add some delay for every process to terminate and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work definitely, As you are saying that some process are not getting terminated this might of because TerminateProcess() is asynchronous call, it return immediately after initiating TerminateProcess(). And you might be checking immediately after its return. To be sure whether these processes are successfully terminated or not you can use WaitForSingleObject() on handle of your process. for more info read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I don't think that code *can* work, because TerminateProcess() is only called if WaitForSingleObject() fails.  The only reason why WaitForSingleObject() might fail is if the handle is invalid, in which case TerminateProcess() won't work either.  Are you seeing something I've missed?

Comment: @Harry..you can call TerminateProcess() whenever you want there is no boundation on calling of this function. You can check out this on link which I have posted above.

Comment: Yes, you *can* call TerminateProcess() whenever you want, but the *code posted in the question* only calls it if WaitForSingleObject() fails.